# ajax запрос без обработчика

Tags: ajax

Здраствуйте!
Как вывести обновленную информацию без всяких обработчиков то есть как только поменялось что то в бд mysql чтоб страница отображала измененные данные
.....

```
request.open("GET"url,true);
.. request.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
if(request.readyState != 4)return;
if(request.status = 200)
{
document.GetElementByID("somediv").innerHtml = request.responseText;
}
}
```

этот код работает но показывает обновленные даные только после перезагрузки наверно потому что нет обработчика

Answer (score 1):

1. if(request.status =**=** 200) // пропустили =
2. эту функцию нужно выполнять все время, а не 1 раз.
3. Если вы хотите моментальное реагирование на изменения - посмотрите в сторону webSocket (но думаю это пока лишнее)

Comment: 1 ну я поменял = на == то же самое 
2 а как выполнять все время? здесь нет кнопок кликов нужно просто при измененнии какой то ячейки в бд отображать новое значение
3 похалуйста подскажите простенькое решение без соккетов

Comment: http://javascript.ru/setInterval

Answer (score 1):

Так совершай запрос регулярно по таймеру.

Comment: а это не будет загружать страницу?

Comment: я имею виду лишнюю нагрузку на сервер

Comment: Естественно будет. Хотите выполнять действия без нагрузки? Это как отжиматься и не уставать) Не думаю, что у вас там 5-гиговая база, чтобы нагрузка сильно ощущалась. Главное не раз в секудну, а 10 хотя бы (и то это часто).

Comment: Верно. Как-то же надо получать данные? нагрузка слишком большой не должна быть, только интервал подгрузки разумный выбирайте.

Comment: это не подходит потому что данные должны показываться сразу после изменения например как в чате или почтовой службе. допустим у пользователя сообщения сохраняются в базе сейчас 10 сообщений а через 5 секунд 11 и как только изменилось количество нужно отображать их или к примеру в чате пользователю кто то напписал и сразу должно появляться измененное содержимое

Comment: Ну тогда вам либо в вебсокеты(это единственное решение, доступное *почти* на js), либо пишите своего клиента, либо, как варианты - флэш/ява. Все очень хорошо гуглится. Учтите, что постоянное получение информации будет грузить еще больше + много других ограничений и трудностей.

Comment: Спасибо всем!! я уже разобрался и сделал без таймеров и без вебсоккетов

Comment: можеш реализовать это с помощью comet server на сервере будет работать скрипт который будет проверять изменение и если они есть передавать клиенту